# Local NodeJS Server TCP Connect to Device on Home Network

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, tcp

Just heads up, I'm barely a programmer, just work for USPS. I'm trying to pick this up to make a way to remotely control an old video switcher that's connected to my home network via ethernet. The manual says you just need to open TCP connection to its IP on port 23, and I've confirmed it works via telnet to send it's supported commands.

After some looking around, it appeared that my best bet was to set up a local NodeJS server + WebSockets and have it listen/communicate to that IP/port. But I feel like I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here, as when I use the Smart Web Socket extension to test it, it appears I'm somehow just connecting back to my laptop instead of the switch in the code. Important bits:

```
const serverPort = 8080,
    http = require("http"),
    express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    WebSocket = require("ws"),
    websocketServer = new WebSocket.Server({ server }),
    net = require("net"),
    vSwitcher = new net.Socket(),
    vIP = '192.168.x.x', // switcher's IP on home network
    vPort = 23; // switcher's port
    
    // on the first websock connection to server, establish initial connection to switcher

websocketServer.on('connection', (websocketClient) => {

   //connect to switcher at specified port/address

    vSwitcher.connect(vPort, vIP, function(){
        
        var address = vSwitcher.address();
        var check = address.address; 

        // 'check' variable is returning my laptop's IP???
        
        vSwitcher.write("Q\r\n");
        webSocketClient.send(`{ "ip" : ${check} }`);
        
    });

  //when command is received from client, send it to video switcher & catch switcher's response

    webSocketClient.on('command', (command) => {


        vSwitcher.connect(vPort, vIP, function(){  
        vSwitcher.write(command + "\r\n"); // write the message to the switcher
        
        vSwitcher.on('data', function(data) { // grab the switcher's response and send it to the client for whatever else

//etc
```

TL;DR I have a video switcher on my home network, and I'm trying to use Node + JS to listen/send commands to it from a local client browser using a TCP connection. (Browser, to Node Server, to Video Switch, and back). But the test scripts I'm using suggest I'm just connecting it back to my laptop. Any suggestions or better ways to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: [`vSwitcher.address()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_address) will return the address of the socket on your computer (which is the server) so that is fine. Why do you think the code you have is not working in any [error handler](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error)?

Comment: @tbking Hah, that helped. In the error handler misspelled "error", which is why I wasn't getting an error to return. And I didn't notice I had it set to try and connect twice, which was the error holding everything up. Haha, live and learn. Thanks.